# goto label trick in a macro for condition

Tags: c, if-statement, macros, goto, c89

There was one evil macro trick I DON'T REMEMBER and it was a lot like this:

```
public :
var = 3;
}
```

Which should expand to

```
if(route == ROOTING_PUBLIC)
{
    var = 3;
}
```

How can I achieve something like this ?

Comment: Huh?  Why would you even care about such grossness (assuming it were possible)?

Comment: I don't think it is grossness. It looks much cleaner to me and like an add-up for a specific environment. In the project I am working on.. this will be certainly a good use of this trick I've seen before.

Comment: I think you will find yourself in the minority, then!  Let's assume this were possible (it isn't).  You'd be hiding control-flow and scoping behind syntax which looks like something completely different.  Anyone coming across this code would be completely misled.

Comment: Evil macro tricks are by definition evil. Don't be evil. It may look clean or clever to you. Which is fine if you are the only one that will ever be exposed to it. But if it's meant for the eyes of others you may want to consider what kind of curses evil code like this may produce.

Comment: True, but I think this is by far not the worst C-reinventing I've encountered during well.. life. And I think it is relatively safe.

Comment: @kaylum, a tad bit circular, or perhaps just tautological.  One could just as easily say "amazingly good macro tricks are amazingly good by definition."  At any rate, the _worst_ macro is still better than OOP, so least evil C macros have that going for them...

Answer (score 3):

Macros are used to reduce clutter; though a lot of clutter indicates problems with the program structure.

The OP's notion of the possible macro does not match C-syntax.  But something along those lines might be:

```
#define if_ROOTED(name) if (ROOTED_##name & input) { output = e##name; }

#define ROOTED_FIRST 16
#define ROOTED_SECOND 64

#define eFIRST 1
#define eSECOND 2

    if_ROOTED(FIRST);
    if_ROOTED(SECOND);
```

where *input* and *output* and the repetitive test are the "clutter" to be eliminated.  Making a table would be a better way to reduce clutter; however OP asked for a hint about macros.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I found the implementation of such bad idea, I also could understand the deeper sense in it.

---

**The code**

```
#define public if(route == ROOTING_PUBLIC) { public_offset
```

---

**The usage**

```
public :
    var = 3;
} // <-- makes no sense
```

---

**The idea**

To avoid loops, to reduce the spaghetti code and to demonstrate more exotic code. It will be better to be implemented with an id system as such:

```
#define public(id) if(route == ROOTING_PUBLIC) { public_##id
```

And then if the user decides to loop the code (that by semantics will be invoked solely "publicly"):

```
public(2) :
    var = 3;
    if(var > 3) goto public_2; // or #define repeat(x, id) goto x##_##id
}
```

Even better version of it will include the omitting of magic numbers, replacing it with `user_id`

Comment: One drawback to putting one "{" within the macro is that it prevents you from using the text-editor to check balance of curly-braces.

Comment: As a matter of facts yes. Bracket-matching feature will be highly confused on that one.

Comment: A `switch` statement would be far more readable and would not require macro obfuscation.

Comment: Back before c89, I used compilers which accepted an unbalanced `"` in a macro.

Comment: @wallyk I am open for more efficient solutions that stick to the idea.